# Disabling multilib support in Bitbake?

Tags: linux, embedded, bitbake

I've recently run into a problem with Bitbake where the image I am generating (aarch64/dragonboard410c rpb-console-image from qcom).

For a reason unbeknownst to me Bitbake is generating two shared library directories `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`. This is causing several applications to fail when I try to launch them.

I can resolve the issue short term by symlinking the entirety of `/usr/lib64` into `/usr/lib` but this seems like a brittle solution.

Can anyone point to what might be causing this issue?

Comment: It can depends on one of recipes you are using. If you are lucky you can check if `MULTILIBS` is defined in your `local.conf`.

Comment: Normal reason for this behaviour is to allow 64 and 32 bit software to run on a platform. Which problems does this cause? Note that we are programming Q&A site. Your questions does not look like it follows site-rules, it is more about OS/platform-specific problems.

Comment: In essence, the problem is some applications fail (specifically Python3, and GDB because of its dependency on Python3) because they are unable to find the necessary shared libraries. I have tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to remedy this but this has not helped. Symlinking all of lib64 into lib seems to be the only working solution right now.

@Olaf: Please point me to a better location for this query. I can see how it is definitely not programming but it is unclear what subject this question actually falls under. It is definitely a Linux compilation problem but through Bitbake...